# SharePoint Web Part Categorization Issue

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, wss, edit, categories

As default, SharePoint put Web Parts we deployed into Miscellaneous in Edit Mode. But I want to categorize them into special topics. I found some solutions about this issue but it didn't work. For instance, in web part project, following codes are from MyWebPart.webpart file:

```
<data>
  <properties>
    <property name="Title" type="string">MyWebPart Web Part</property>
    <property name="Description" type="string">MyWebPart Description</property>
    <property name="Group" type="string">General Web Parts</property> // I added this
  </properties>
</data>
```

When I edit the title and the description, and deploy the project, nothing changes. I also add these property tags into MyWebPart.xml file but it makes no difference.

Even I try IISRESET. No solution..

If I miss something about this categorization issue please tell me. I appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

you have to add the "Group" property to the Elements.xml and not in your *.webpart file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="MyWebPart" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="MyWebPart\MyWebPart.webpart" Url="MyWebPart.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="MyGroup" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: I'll also add that the Group name is case-sensitive, so take care across your projects to make sure the Group names all match exactly. Otherwise you'll end up multiple entries for a single logical group.

Comment: I already put that code but it didn't work. I haven't got an Elements.xml but MyWebPart.xml, I found out the solution. I can categorize the gallery in Site Settings easily. No code needed.